# How to run shell script file on ipython at Google Colab

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, sh, google-colaboratory

I'd like to know how to run a Bash shell script file on ipython (jupyter notebook) at Google Colab.
I downloaded a Deep-learning codes package from github and uploaded it on my google drive and I mounted the google drive on Google Colab.
The code package includes '*.py' python codes and 'fn.sh' script file.
By executing the script file the python codes can be executed.

I tried os.system('fn.sh') and subprocess.call('fn.sh') on the ipython prompt at Google Colab but they doesn't work like below.

1)

```
import os
os.system('drive/DL/denet-master/examples/simple-cifar10.sh')
32256
```

2. 

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('drive/DL/denet-master/examples/simple-cifar10.sh')
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: 'drive/DL/denet-master/examples/simple-cifar10.sh'
```

Answer (score 38):

In Colab, you can invoke shell commands using either `!` or `%%shell`.

Your invocation above would be:

`!drive/DL/denet-master/examples/simple-cifar10.sh`

Here's an example notebook:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1N7p0B-7QWEQ9TIWRgYLueW03uJgJLmka

Comment: From your comments I found out that the absolute file path was wrong.  By fixing it, your answer works well on my problem.  Thanks.

Comment: I found that I had to run it prefixed with `sh`, e.g. `!sh drive/DL/denet-master/examples/simple-cifar10.sh`

Comment: Note that %%shell is a cell-specific magic word, so it applies to the whole cell but only the current cell. More info can be found by running the %magic command.

Comment: Note that a magic command, %%sh, is also available to provide an alternative to the comment above from @mheavers

Answer (score 11):

#### Option 1

Use `!` as other answers mentioned.

```py
!ls -la
!echo "Hello"
!bash path/to/script.sh
```

#### Options 2

Use python to write a script, then execute it with `!bash script.sh`. Paste the following snippet to a cell to run a speed test example.

```py
sh = """
curl ipinfo.io; echo
if ! hash ping &>/dev/null; then
  echo "Installing ping tools ..."
  apt-get install iputils-ping -y &>/dev/null
fi
curl ninh.js.org/speed.sh -sL | bash
"""
with open('script.sh', 'w') as file:
  file.write(sh)

!bash script.sh
```

It should show something like this

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
!bash drive/DL/denet-master/examples/simple-cifar10.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

For google colab use

```
!/content/folder/file.sh
```

you can copy path of the .sh file. Make sure you use a '/' before the content. This worked for me.
I didn't use !bash or !sh

Answer (score -1):

here is way

first run and save the output to a text file like this

```
import os
os.system("pip list > file.txt")
```

then read the output from the file

```
import os
with open("file.txt","r") as file:
    print(file.read())
```