# Error in google colab /bin/sh: Permission denied

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, sh, google-colaboratory, executable

I downloaded [this code](https://github.com/seshnadathur/Revolver) from github and it runs fine on my local computer, but I need to use in google colab, where it throws errors. More precisely, what I get as error output is:

```
/bin/sh: 1: ./rbox: Permission denied
/bin/sh: 1: ./qhull: Permission denied
...
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'python_tools.fastmodules'
```

The full error message can be seen [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f1DKSSgaDk2wzSTT-uMXK85gqZY9D_Qc/view?usp=sharing) as well as in the notebook [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1RhorUVHwxFvX9KsnOfgqolhYmrjvJgYH?usp=sharing). I tried different suggestions for giving permission for executing the files `./rbox` and `./qhull` - I inserted a new cell before the code snippet containing

```
!chmod 755 -R /content/gdrive/MyDrive/PhD/revolver/qhull/src/ #pointing to the file-directory
```

or

```
!chmod 755 ./rbox
```

or

```
!chmod +x /content/gdrive/MyDrive/PhD/revolver/qhull/src/rbox
```

but none of them solves the error. How can I resolve the error message? It would be also great if someone can download the github code from the link into google drive confirm that he can run it without errors. Installations instructions are provided on the github page, you can use my [params.py](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17GZplG7I2P8f7mnAr7I-NJE2rgOiZ7tx/view?usp=sharing) file and within it you can set `tracer_file` to point at this [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Xp1e8pm6DVhHZOSTXYN-iPE6q3PrlDv8/view?usp=sharing) that I used, or any dummy csv-file with 3 columns. Tnx! Your contribution would help me run an astrophysics simulation for my PhD

Comment: Hmmm.. what happens if run `./rbox` or `./qhull` [manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52343308/how-to-run-shell-script-file-on-ipython-at-google-colab)? Looks like the main problem is that you can't execute these binaries. May be here is some access right limitations in colab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a mistake by confusing the location of my files. There were different copies of the `rbox` and `qhull` files in different folders, so I should have done

```
!chmod +x /content/gdrive/MyDrive/PhD/revolver/qhull/rbox
!chmod +x /content/gdrive/MyDrive/PhD/revolver/qhull/qhull
```

instead of

```
!chmod +x /content/gdrive/MyDrive/PhD/revolver/qhull/src/rbox
!chmod +x /content/gdrive/MyDrive/PhD/revolver/qhull/src/qhull
```